# Unable to connect to Windows VPN in Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: 11.10, vpn

I am very very new bie in the world of Ubuntu.  I have recently installed Ubuntu 11.10 and I am not able to connect to Windows VPN.

When I login to Windows 8 I am able to connect to VPN using default Windows VPN connection.

Any help pointers?

Comment: We would need to know what type of VPN you are connecting to. (PPTP, L2TP, IPsec, etc).

Comment: I am able to connect to VPN using windows default VPN connector.  I guess it uses PPTP.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

How to set up VPN in Ubuntu **(when you know the parameters to configure)**:

Click the network icon in the panel → `VPN Connections` → `Configure VPN`.

[image: addvpn1]

Go to VPN tab → `Add`.

[image: addvpn2]

`Create`.

[image: addvpn3]

Enter settings, optionally mark `Connect automatically`, `Save`.

[image: addvpn4]

You can connect via the network icon in the panel.

[image: connectvpn]

Ps. If you're trying to connect to a Windows VPN and still not working, try the below method suggested by Jason Rowe:

Try going into "Advanced" on the VPN tab and enable "Use Point-to-Point encryption (MPPE)", set security to "All Available (Default)" and tick the boxes for "Allow BSD data compression", "Allow Deflate data compression", and "Use TCP header compression".

Comment: Hi,  thanks for your answer,  I have done above settings,  but still I get that it is not able to connect to VPN.

Comment: I can't seem to figure out what package that icon on the panel is inside of.  I can create a VPN connection but not see that.

Answer (score 10):

Thanks for the additional info.

Try going into "Advanced" on the VPN tab and enable "Use Point-to-Point encryption (MPPE)", set security to "All Available (Default)" and tick the boxes for "Allow BSD data compression", "Allow Deflate data compression", and "Use TCP header compression".

Comment: Thanks a lot Jayson, that worked like charm for me :) you are the master :)

Comment: Happy to help, Sudhir. I'm glad it worked for you.

Comment: Finally !!!!!!!!

Answer (score 3):

click "advanced" button, then only select MSCHAP and MSCHAPv2 authentication methods. You'd better select every option in other fields.

Comment: This does not provide a sufficient answer to the question. Try to add more information, and / or examples.

Comment: This was the case for me - though I had to disable MSCHAP and only have MSCHAPv2 checked in order to connect. GG, Microsoft.